# AuthContext Consumer didn't re-render when context is changed

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass some props through a parent and child tree using context.

In the root, I configured as follow:

```
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    const loginHandler = () => {
        setAuthenticated(true);

    return(
            <AuthContext.Provider
                value={{ authenticated: authenticated, login: loginHandler }}
            >
                {showCockpit ? (
                    <Cockpit showPerson={showPerson} toggle={togglePersonHandler} />
                ) : null}
            </AuthContext.Provider>)
    };
```

In the child level 1 which is right below the root:

```
Cockpit.js

<AuthContext.Consumer>
                {(context) => (
                    <StyledButton onClick={() => context.login()}>Log in</StyledButton>
                )}
</AuthContext.Consumer>
```

In the child level 2 which is under level 1 child Persons is:

```
Person.js

<AuthContext.Consumer>
                {(context) =>
                    context.authenticated ? (
                        <h1>Authenticated!</h1>
                    ) : (
                        <h1>Please log in</h1>
                    )
                }
</AuthContext.Consumer>
```

Current configuration should show "Please log in" at the start and when user press "Log in" button, it will automatically change to "Authenticated". In this scenario, however, It only show at the start: "Please log in", but the value won't change when I pressed "Log in".

Note that I've used console logs and found out that the value of the state "Authenticated" did change in the context from false to true. Does anyone know why It happen like this? Is it because there's some data lost while passing from the parent to the child?

Comment: Can you add your code [here](http://react.new/). This code does not give clarity.

Comment: Where is the Person used? i dont see it inside the context

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-leakey-md4tk?file=/src/registerServiceWorker) is the link to the code @ShubhamVerma

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan You can check the link as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in the app.js
The person component is outside the context provider

Change it like below

```
 < AuthContext.Provider
value={{ authenticated: authenticated, login: loginHandler }}>
{showCockpit ? (
  < Cockpit showPerson={showPerson} toggle={togglePersonHandler} />
) : null}

{showPerson ? (
  <Persons
    persons={personState}
    clicked={deletePersonHandler}
    changed={nameChangeHandler}
  />
) : null}
  < / AuthContext.Provider>
```

When you access the context outside the provider it will provide you the default value which you gave when creating it.

You can see the sample here

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-bas-nbqlu